# Shadow detection using hsv color model

Tags: detection, shadow, using, hsv

I'm new to image processing. All I want to do is to remove the shadow of human. I'm try to implement [this paper](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~hugomcp/visaoComp/docs/Shadow_removal_5.pdf)'s shadow detection but I'm getting error saying that:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Bpos (line 37)
       w= (cfv(i,j)/pv(i,j));

Please help me out. Many thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have done:

```
mov = VideoReader('person05_walking_d4_uncomp.avi');
p=imread('c.png');
p=rgb2hsv(p);
ph=p(:,:,1);
ps=p(:,:,2);
pv=p(:,:,3);
alphaV=0.2;
betaV=0.8;


opFolder = fullfile('F:\imagelab', 'Bpos');
if ~exist(opFolder, 'dir')
mkdir(opFolder);
end

numFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames;
numFramesWritten = 0;
for t = 1 : numFrames
currFrame = read(mov, t);
currFrame=rgb2hsv(currFrame);
figure;imshow(currFrame);
cfh=currFrame(:,:,1);
figure;
imshow(cfh);
cfs=currFrame(:,:,2);
figure;imshow(cfs);
cfv=currFrame(:,:,3);
figure;imshow(cfv);

[m,n]=size(currFrame);
single=zeros(m,n);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
%        a=cfv(i,j);
%        progIndication = sprintf('Wrote frame  %d.',a);
%        disp(progIndication);
       w= (cfv(i,j)/pv(i,j));
       progIndication = sprintf('Wrote frame  %d.',w);
       disp(progIndication);
       sat=cfs(i,j)-ps(i,j);
        progIndication = sprintf('sat frame  %d.',w);
       disp(progIndication);
       hue=cfh(i,j)-ph(i,j);
        progIndication = sprintf('hue frame  %d.',w);
       disp(progIndication);
       if(w>=alphaV && w<=betaV && sat<=-0.3 && hue <=0.2)
           single(i,j)=1; 
       else
            single(i,j)=0;
       end
    end
end
imshow(single);




opBaseFileName = sprintf('%3.3d.png', t);
opFullFileName = fullfile(opFolder, opBaseFileName);
imwrite(single, opFullFileName, 'png');

end


end
```